# How to keep representation of FKs uniform in input/output (RESTful JSON API)

Tags: json, api, rest

We're writing our first non-XML API, and I want to ask about the best practices of representing related resources across the API. Let me explain it on a `user` resource and its related resource - `organization`.

In **XML** this is pretty straightforward:

1. *Response body (GET)* - it contains resource IDs as well as URIs:

   ```
   GET /users/321/

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <user>
       <!-- ... --->
       <organization name="Lorem Ipsum Ltd." href="/organizations/123/">123</organization>
   </user>
   ```
2. *Request body (POST/PUT/PATCH)* - uses IDs:

   ```
   PATCH /users/321

   ...&organization=123
   ```
3. *URI filters* - uses IDs of related resources:

   ```
   GET /users/?organization=123

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <users>
       <!-- ... --->
   </users>
   ```

Now, since **JSON** doesn't use attributes, it's not a 1:1 transition.

1. *Response body (GET):*

   Instead of using IDs as values, we switched to URIs in order to adhere to the connectedness principle of REST:

   ```
   GET /users/321/

   {
       ...,
       "organization": "/organizations/123"
   }
   ```
2. *Request body (POST/PUT/PATCH)* - accepts URIs (example not encoded for sake of readability):

   ```
   PATCH /users/321

   ...&organization=/organizations/123/
   ```
3. *URI filters* - in order to keep the URIs clean, we still use IDs instead of URIs when filtering via GET parameters:

   ```
   GET /users/?organization=123

   {
       "users": [
           ...
       ]
   }
   ```

The last bit breaks the uniformity of values (ID vs. URI) between request and response, but we'd prefer using IDs instead of URIs because IDs are more readable and because there may be cases where we need to put more than one value in a filter (e.g. `?organization__in=123,124`).

So my question is, **how do you keep request/response representation of related resources uniform across your API**? Any best practices, standards, or just common sense? Or perhaps is the above an unnecessary concern?

*Edit*: To clarify, **I'm asking about how would you design the API in terms of URI structure (GET parameters) and format of request/response data**. I'm *not* asking about the technical implementation.

One approach we though of is to switch to a more verbose representation which gives users of the API a bit more data, but it still doesn't solve the uniformity problem. Example:

```
GET /users/321/

{
    ...,
    "organization": {
        "ud":   123,
        "name": "Lorem Ipsum Ltd.",
        "uri":  "/organizations/123"
    }
}
```

Note - similar question (not duplicate): [REST API - include related object details or just ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337708/rest-api-include-related-object-details-or-just-ids)

Comment: When you are asking for uniformity, am I correct you mean across objects?

Comment: If you mean _across objects_ as between objects that are related via foreign keys, then yes.

Comment: The question shows URI format for a query that filters users by organization - ``/users/?organization=123``. The query uses organization _ID_ in GET parameter, while the response would contain an _URI_ of said organization instead of just its _ID_. This is the inconsistency which I'm pointing out, and I'm seeking advice on how this is commonly handled - i.e. keep it uniform and use either IDs or URIs; or don't worry about it and mix it; or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question and I do see the advantage of having a way to do this.  An interface or inheritance will not work since all you are really returning is a string (figurative).  How about a set of helpers that would act on a type and build the responses for you?  You could pass it T and it would iterate thru the object building the response according to the rules and patterns you design.
You could have a GetBuilder(x) and it would be called from your Get.  This provides a single location for the processing of the returns and provides uniformity.

Comment: I'm sorry, you misunderstood - see my reply to your original comment, please. I'm asking about URI structure and formats of data, not the technical background (on which you're spot on, it's just not what I was asking about).